# How to debug function which is getting called throuh validate_and_run() in R?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I want to debug functions in ShadowCAT package. https://github.com/Karel-Kroeze/ShadowCAT/tree/master/R

Take any internal functions from this package, they are getting called via `validate_and_run()` function. If I go though it I am directly presented an output and I am not able to run through each line of the code I am interested in. What I think `validate_and_run()` creating an environment to call the functions.

For e.g. I am trying to debug `shadowcat` function from the package using following code:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("Karel-Kroeze/ShadowCAT")
library(ShadowCAT)
debug(shadowcat)

alpha_beta <- simulate_testbank(model = "GPCM", number_items = 100, 
                                number_dimensions = 3, number_itemsteps = 3)
model <- "GPCM"
start_items <- list(type = 'fixed', item_keys = c("item33", "item5", "item23"), n = 3)
stop_test <- list(min_n = 4, max_n = 30, target = c(.1, .1, .1))
estimator <- "maximum_aposteriori"
information_summary <- "posterior_determinant"
prior_form <- "normal"
prior_parameters <- list(mu = c(0, 0, 0), Sigma = diag(3))

# Initial call: get key of first item to adminster
call1 <- shadowcat(answers = NULL, estimate = c(0, 0, 0), variance = as.vector(diag(3) * 25), 
                   model = model, alpha = alpha_beta$alpha, beta = alpha_beta$beta, 
                   start_items = start_items, stop_test = stop_test, 
                   estimator = estimator, information_summary = information_summary,
                   prior_form = prior_form, prior_parameters = prior_parameters)
```

In above `shadowcat()` function there ane many internal functions written but I do not see they are getting called anywhere in the `shadowcat()`. My speculation is that it is getting called in `validate_and_run()` function.

My question is how can I debug those internal functions inside the `shadowcat()` and see what each variable is storing and what are the inputs of the internal functions when they are getting called?

**EDIT 1:**

In any usual R function, when one debugs it, you can move your debugging cursor (yellow highlighted line) line by line by clicking on next in RStudio. Also, once you have gone over that line of code , you can see the value of the variable by printing the variable name on console. This I am not able to do in shadowcat() function. Internal function codes are written but they are never called in visible form. I need to see where they are getting called and need to debug through them

Any leads appreciated.

**EDIT 2**
Main body of the code:

```
function (answers, estimate, variance, model, alpha, beta, start_items, 
    stop_test, estimator, information_summary, prior_form = NULL, 
    prior_parameters = NULL, guessing = NULL, eta = NULL, constraints_and_characts = NULL, 
    lower_bound = NULL, upper_bound = NULL, safe_eap = FALSE, 
    eap_estimation_procedure = "riemannsum") 
{
    result <- function() {
        switch_to_maximum_aposteriori <- estimator == "maximum_likelihood" && 
            !is.null(lower_bound) && !is.null(upper_bound)
        estimator <- get_estimator(switch_to_maximum_aposteriori = switch_to_maximum_aposteriori)
        prior_form <- get_prior_form(switch_to_maximum_aposteriori = switch_to_maximum_aposteriori)
        prior_parameters <- get_prior_parameters(switch_to_maximum_aposteriori = switch_to_maximum_aposteriori)
        beta <- get_beta()
        guessing <- get_guessing()
        number_items <- nrow(alpha)
        number_dimensions <- ncol(alpha)
        number_itemsteps_per_item <- number_non_missing_cells_per_row(beta)
        lp_constraints_and_characts <- get_lp_constraints_and_characts(number_items = number_items)
        item_keys <- rownames(alpha)
        item_keys_administered <- names(answers)
        item_keys_available <- get_item_keys_available(item_keys_administered = item_keys_administered, 
            item_keys = item_keys)
        attr(estimate, "variance") <- matrix(variance, ncol = number_dimensions)
        estimate <- update_person_estimate(estimate = estimate, 
            answers_vector = unlist(answers), item_indices_administered = match(item_keys_administered, 
                item_keys), number_dimensions = number_dimensions, 
            alpha = alpha, beta = beta, guessing = guessing, 
            number_itemsteps_per_item = number_itemsteps_per_item, 
            estimator = estimator, prior_form = prior_form, prior_parameters = prior_parameters)
        continue_test <- !terminate_test(number_answers = length(answers), 
            estimate = estimate, min_n = stop_test$min_n, max_n = stop_test$max_n, 
            variance_target = stop_test$target, cutoffs = stop_test$cutoffs)
        if (continue_test) {
            index_new_item <- get_next_item(start_items = start_items, 
                information_summary = information_summary, lp_constraints = lp_constraints_and_characts$lp_constraints, 
                lp_characters = lp_constraints_and_characts$lp_chars, 
                estimate = estimate, model = model, answers = unlist(answers), 
                prior_form = prior_form, prior_parameters = prior_parameters, 
                available = match(item_keys_available, item_keys), 
                administered = match(item_keys_administered, 
                  item_keys), number_items = number_items, number_dimensions = number_dimensions, 
                estimator = estimator, alpha = alpha, beta = beta, 
                guessing = guessing, number_itemsteps_per_item = number_itemsteps_per_item, 
                stop_test = stop_test, eap_estimation_procedure = eap_estimation_procedure)
            key_new_item <- item_keys[index_new_item]
        }
        else {
            key_new_item <- NULL
        }
        list(key_new_item = as.scalar2(key_new_item), continue_test = as.scalar2(continue_test), 
            estimate = as.vector(estimate), variance = as.vector(attr(estimate, 
                "variance")), answers = answers)
    }
    update_person_estimate <- function(estimate, answers_vector, 
        item_indices_administered, number_dimensions, alpha, 
        beta, guessing, number_itemsteps_per_item, estimator, 
        prior_form, prior_parameters) {
        if (length(answers) > start_items$n) 
            estimate_latent_trait(estimate = estimate, answers = answers_vector, 
                prior_form = prior_form, prior_parameters = prior_parameters, 
                model = model, administered = item_indices_administered, 
                number_dimensions = number_dimensions, estimator = estimator, 
                alpha = alpha, beta = beta, guessing = guessing, 
                number_itemsteps_per_item = number_itemsteps_per_item, 
                safe_eap = safe_eap, eap_estimation_procedure = eap_estimation_procedure)
        else estimate
    }
    get_item_keys_available <- function(item_keys_administered, 
        item_keys) {
        if (is.null(item_keys_administered)) 
            item_keys
        else item_keys[-which(item_keys %in% item_keys_administered)]
    }
    get_beta <- function() {
        if (model == "GPCM" && is.null(beta) && !is.null(eta)) 
            row_cumsum(eta)
        else beta
    }
    get_guessing <- function() {
        if (is.null(guessing)) 
            matrix(0, nrow = nrow(as.matrix(alpha)), ncol = 1, 
                dimnames = list(rownames(alpha), NULL))
        else guessing
    }
    get_estimator <- function(switch_to_maximum_aposteriori) {
        if (switch_to_maximum_aposteriori) 
            "maximum_aposteriori"
        else estimator
    }
    get_prior_form <- function(switch_to_maximum_aposteriori) {
        if (switch_to_maximum_aposteriori) 
            "uniform"
        else prior_form
    }
    get_prior_parameters <- function(switch_to_maximum_aposteriori) {
        if (switch_to_maximum_aposteriori) 
            list(lower_bound = lower_bound, upper_bound = upper_bound)
        else prior_parameters
    }
    get_lp_constraints_and_characts <- function(number_items) {
        if (is.null(constraints_and_characts)) 
            NULL
        else constraints_lp_format(max_n = stop_test$max_n, number_items = number_items, 
            characteristics = constraints_and_characts$characteristics, 
            constraints = constraints_and_characts$constraints)
    }
    validate <- function() {
        if (is.null(estimate)) 
            return(add_error("estimate", "is missing"))
        if (is.null(variance)) 
            return(add_error("variance", "is missing"))
        if (!is.vector(variance)) 
            return(add_error("variance", "should be entered as vector"))
        if (sqrt(length(variance)) != round(sqrt(length(variance)))) 
            return(add_error("variance", "should be a covariance matrix turned into a vector"))
        if (is.null(model)) 
            return(add_error("model", "is missing"))
        if (is.null(alpha)) 
            return(add_error("alpha", "is missing"))
        if (is.null(start_items)) 
            return(add_error("start_items", "is missing"))
        if (is.null(stop_test)) 
            return(add_error("stop_test", "is missing"))
        if (is.null(estimator)) 
            return(add_error("estimator", "is missing"))
        if (is.null(information_summary)) 
            return(add_error("information_summary", "is missing"))
        if (!is.matrix(alpha) || is.null(rownames(alpha))) 
            return(add_error("alpha", "should be a matrix with item keys as row names"))
        if (!is.null(beta) && (!is.matrix(beta) || is.null(rownames(beta)))) 
            return(add_error("beta", "should be a matrix with item keys as row names"))
        if (!is.null(eta) && (!is.matrix(eta) || is.null(rownames(eta)))) 
            return(add_error("eta", "should be a matrix with item keys as row names"))
        if (!is.null(guessing) && (!is.matrix(guessing) || ncol(guessing) != 
            1 || is.null(rownames(guessing)))) 
            return(add_error("guessing", "should be a single column matrix with item keys as row names"))
        if (!is.null(start_items$type) && start_items$type == 
            "random_by_dimension" && length(start_items$n_by_dimension) %not_in% 
            c(1, length(estimate))) 
            return(add_error("start_items", "length of n_by_dimension should be a scalar or vector of the length of estimate"))
        if (!row_names_are_equal(rownames(alpha), list(alpha, 
            beta, eta, guessing))) 
            add_error("alpha_beta_eta_guessing", "should have equal row names, in same order")
        if (!is.null(beta) && !na_only_end_rows(beta)) 
            add_error("beta", "can only contain NA at the end of rows, no values allowed after an NA in a row")
        if (!is.null(eta) && !na_only_end_rows(eta)) 
            add_error("eta", "can only contain NA at the end of rows, no values allowed after an NA in a row")
        if (length(estimate) != ncol(alpha)) 
            add_error("estimate", "length should be equal to the number of columns of the alpha matrix")
        if (length(estimate)^2 != length(variance)) 
            add_error("variance", "should have a length equal to the length of estimate squared")
        if (is.null(answers) && !is.positive.definite(matrix(variance, 
            ncol = sqrt(length(variance))))) 
            add_error("variance", "matrix is not positive definite")
        if (model %not_in% c("3PLM", "GPCM", "SM", "GRM")) 
            add_error("model", "of unknown type")
        if (model != "GPCM" && is.null(beta)) 
            add_error("beta", "is missing")
        if (model == "GPCM" && is.null(beta) && is.null(eta)) 
            add_error("beta_and_eta", "are both missing; define at least one of them")
        if (model == "GPCM" && !is.null(beta) && !is.null(eta) && 
            !all(row_cumsum(eta) == beta)) 
            add_error("beta_and_eta", "objects do not match")
        if (estimator != "maximum_likelihood" && is.null(prior_form)) 
            add_error("prior_form", "is missing")
        if (estimator != "maximum_likelihood" && is.null(prior_parameters)) 
            add_error("prior_parameters", "is missing")
        if (!is.null(prior_form) && prior_form %not_in% c("normal", 
            "uniform")) 
            add_error("prior_form", "of unknown type")
        if (!is.null(prior_form) && !is.null(prior_parameters) && 
            prior_form == "uniform" && (is.null(prior_parameters$lower_bound) || 
            is.null(prior_parameters$upper_bound))) 
            add_error("prior_form_is_uniform", "so prior_parameters should contain lower_bound and upper_bound")
        if (!is.null(prior_form) && !is.null(prior_parameters) && 
            prior_form == "normal" && (is.null(prior_parameters$mu) || 
            is.null(prior_parameters$Sigma))) 
            add_error("prior_form_is_normal", "so prior_parameters should contain mu and Sigma")
        if (!is.null(prior_parameters$mu) && length(prior_parameters$mu) != 
            length(estimate)) 
            add_error("prior_parameters_mu", "should have same length as estimate")
        if (!is.null(prior_parameters$Sigma) && (!is.matrix(prior_parameters$Sigma) || 
            !all(dim(prior_parameters$Sigma) == c(length(estimate), 
                length(estimate))) || !is.positive.definite(prior_parameters$Sigma))) 
            add_error("prior_parameters_sigma", "should be a square positive definite matrix, with dimensions equal to the length of estimate")
        if (!is.null(prior_parameters$lower_bound) && !is.null(prior_parameters$upper_bound) && 
            (length(prior_parameters$lower_bound) != length(estimate) || 
                length(prior_parameters$upper_bound) != length(estimate))) 
            add_error("prior_parameters_bounds", "should contain lower and upper bound of the same length as estimate")
        if (is.null(stop_test$max_n)) 
            add_error("stop_test", "contains no max_n")
        if (!is.null(stop_test$max_n) && stop_test$max_n > nrow(alpha)) 
            add_error("stop_test_max_n", "is larger than the number of items in the item bank")
        if (!is.null(stop_test$max_n) && !is.null(stop_test$cutoffs) && 
            (!is.matrix(stop_test$cutoffs) || nrow(stop_test$cutoffs) < 
                stop_test$max_n || ncol(stop_test$cutoffs) != 
                length(estimate) || any(is.na(stop_test$cutoffs)))) 
            add_error("stop_test_cutoffs", "should be a matrix without missing values, and number of rows equal to max_n and number of columns equal to the number of dimensions")
        if (start_items$n == 0 && information_summary == "posterior_expected_kullback_leibler") 
            add_error("start_items", "requires n > 0 for posterior expected kullback leibler information summary")
        if (!is.null(start_items$type) && start_items$type == 
            "random_by_dimension" && length(start_items$n_by_dimension) == 
            length(estimate) && start_items$n != sum(start_items$n_by_dimension)) 
            add_error("start_items_n", "contains inconsistent information. Total length of start phase and sum of length per dimension do not match (n != sum(n_by_dimension)")
        if (!is.null(start_items$type) && start_items$type == 
            "random_by_dimension" && length(start_items$n_by_dimension) == 
            1 && start_items$n != sum(rep(start_items$n_by_dimension, 
            length(estimate)))) 
            add_error("start_items_n", "contains inconsistent information. Total length of start phase and sum of length per dimension do not match")
        if (!is.null(stop_test$cutoffs) && !is.matrix(stop_test$cutoffs)) 
            add_error("stop_test", "contains cutoff values in non-matrix format")
        if (!all(names(answers) %in% rownames(alpha))) 
            add_error("answers", "contains non-existing key")
        if (estimator %not_in% c("maximum_likelihood", "maximum_aposteriori", 
            "expected_aposteriori")) 
            add_error("estimator", "of unknown type")
        if (information_summary %not_in% c("determinant", "posterior_determinant", 
            "trace", "posterior_trace", "posterior_expected_kullback_leibler")) 
            add_error("information_summary", "of unknown type")
        if (estimator == "maximum_likelihood" && information_summary %in% 
            c("posterior_determinant", "posterior_trace", "posterior_expected_kullback_leibler")) 
            add_error("estimator_is_maximum_likelihood", "so using a posterior information summary makes no sense")
        if (estimator != "maximum_likelihood" && (!is.null(lower_bound) || 
            !is.null(upper_bound))) 
            add_error("bounds", "can only be defined if estimator is maximum likelihood")
        if (!is.null(lower_bound) && length(lower_bound) %not_in% 
            c(1, length(estimate))) 
            add_error("lower_bound", "length of lower bound should be a scalar or vector of the length of estimate")
        if (!is.null(upper_bound) && length(upper_bound) %not_in% 
            c(1, length(estimate))) 
            add_error("upper_bound", "length of upper bound should be a scalar or vector of the length of estimate")
        if (!no_missing_information(constraints_and_characts$characteristics, 
            constraints_and_characts$constraints)) 
            add_error("constraints_and_characts", "constraints and characteristics should either be defined both or not at all")
        if (!characteristics_correct_format(constraints_and_characts$characteristics, 
            number_items = nrow(alpha))) 
            add_error("characteristics", "should be a data frame with number of rows equal to the number of items in the item bank")
        if (!constraints_correct_structure(constraints_and_characts$constraints)) 
            add_error("constraints_structure", "should be a list of length three lists, with elements named 'name', 'op', 'target'")
        if (!constraints_correct_names(constraints_and_characts$constraints, 
            constraints_and_characts$characteristics)) 
            add_error("constraints_name_elements", "should be defined as described in the details section of constraints_lp_format()")
        if (!constraints_correct_operators(constraints_and_characts$constraints)) 
            add_error("constraints_operator_elements", "should be defined as described in the details section of constraints_lp_format()")
        if (!constraints_correct_targets(constraints_and_characts$constraints)) 
            add_error("constraints_target_elements", "should be defined as described in the details section of constraints_lp_format()")
    }
    invalid_result <- function() {
        list(errors = errors())
    }
    validate_and_run()
}
```

**EDIT 3**
validate_and_run() function:

```
function () 
{
    .errors <- list()
    add_error <- function(key, value = TRUE) {
        .errors[key] <<- value
    }
    errors <- function() {
        .errors
    }
    validate_and_runner <- function() {
        if (exists("validate", parent.frame(), inherits = FALSE)) 
            do.call("validate", list(), envir = parent.frame())
        if (exists("test_inner_functions", envir = parent.frame(n = 2), 
            inherits = FALSE)) 
            get("result", parent.frame())
        else if (length(errors()) == 0) 
            do.call("result", list(), envir = parent.frame())
        else do.call("invalid_result", list(), envir = parent.frame())
    }
    for (n in ls(environment())) assign(n, get(n, environment()), 
        parent.frame())
    do.call("validate_and_runner", list(), envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Comment: What exactly does it mean when you say: "... I am not able to run through each line of the code I am interested in". What do you think you should be able to be doing, what are you attempting, and what results are you getting?

Comment: @42- In any usual R function, when one debugs it, you can move your debugging cursor (yellow highlighted line) line by line by clicking on next in R studio. Also, once you have gone over that line of code , you can see the value of the variable by printing the variable name on console.  This I am not able to do in `shadowcat()` function. Internal function codes are written but they are never called in visible form. I need to see where they are getting called and need to debug through them.

Comment: You should put all that in the body of your question. And you should tag the question with [rstudio] since your expectations are specific to a particular environment that not all of us share. It sounds as though the question is really how to debug (or more accurately how to `trace`) a function that is defined within another function.

Comment: Maybe something like `trace(shadowcat,debugonce(function_to_debug),at=line_number_before_validate_and_run_call)` ? (then execute shadowcat call)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper,  I tried your suggestion, it did not work.

Comment: I can't install your package so can't test it, but you should follow 42's suggestion and give us the full body of the function

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, I have updated my question with full body of the code.

Comment: `validate_and_run` seems not to be defined into this function, which means it should be a regular function of the package, try `debug(validate_and_run)` or `debug(ShadowCAT:::validate_and_run)` and you should be able to browse its cose nect time you run the `shadowcat` function

Comment: I had tried that. It is calling some parent.frame() environment which I am not aware of. ( I have added the code for validate_and_run() in edit 3 in my question body.

Comment: Another angle, make a copy of shadowcat function and insert some print calls wherever you want a value to be returned to the console (or use trace to do it in the original function). It will be pretty much like debugging.

Comment: or instead of `print` add `browser()` statements if you want to examine variables interactively. with this messed up coding style I'm not sure though how stable it will be moving from one `browser()` to the next with e.g. `c`